# Merging two images in PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing, gd

I'm building a web application where you can design something, at the end of the process it outputs two images. One is a gif and the other is a jpeg. I am looking to take both images and merge them into one image. However after trying a few techniques none seem to work.

My script is as follows:

```
$imgl = $_GET['img1'];
$img2 = $_GET['img2'];


$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('$imgl');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('$img2');

// Copy and merge
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

However the image that is displayed is just shows a non image icon. The variables $img1 and $img2 contain an image path, to a folder where the images exsist. I know this because when I echo the two variables in a html img tag, both images are displayed. Can anyone tell me where my script is going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to do a watermark ?

Comment: well.. in a sense yes, its two images, that have transparent parts so that when placed one on top of the other it show parts of them both. Im just trying to turn the two images into one image. If that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know your example is directly for [PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php) but i also tested it and it does not work for me .. with a little work around it should work

```
$imgl = "a.jpg";
$img2 = "f.gif";

$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgl);
$src = imagecreatefromgif($img2);
imagecolortransparent($src, imagecolorat($src, 0, 0));

$src_x = imagesx($src);
$src_y = imagesy($src);
imagecopymerge($dest, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $src_x, $src_y, 100);

// Output and free from memory
header('Content-Type: image/gif');
imagegif($dest);

imagedestroy($dest);
imagedestroy($src);
```

Comment: Yes i can add the picture output for you

Comment: No, not needed. This works, I had a typ when I typed it out. :) Thank you.

Comment: Is there a way to maintain the transparency within the two original images on output of the new image? if that makes sense?

Comment: Use `imagealphablending($dest, false);` and `imagesavealpha($dest, true);`

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the single quotation marks. They stop PHP from looking up for variables in the string. For more information on quotation mark usage in PHP, take a look [here](http://www.untwistedvortex.com/php-programming-beginners-quotation-marks/).

Means:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgl);
$src = imagecreatefromgif($img2);
```

Additionally, you should do checks whether you want to allow the manipulation of an image.
You allow EVERYONE who knows the names of the GET-parameters to put a possible malicious file path into it. You do not prevent this.

Useful functions are [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), [basename](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and [file_exists](http://php.net/file_exists).

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will fix your problem, but it's certainly a syntax error. This:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg('$imgl');
$src = imagecreatefromgif('$img2');
```

Should be:

```
$dest = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgl);
$src = imagecreatefromgif($img2);
```

You want to pass the values of $img1 and $img2, not the literal strings `'$img1'` and `'$img2'`.

Comment: This is not a syntax error, it is a semantic error. A syntax error causes a runtime error.